# Using a python pretrained Machine Learing model (.pkcls) into VB6.0

Tags: python, vb.net, vb6

I have designed and trained a machine learning model with python programming language, then I saved the model for future usage as a .pkcls file. Is it possible to load the model in VB6.0 or VB.Net environment and use it there?

Comment: I think you can't uses. First: `pickle` module exists only in Python - so it would be problem to load it. Second: to load `pickle` it need Python's classes used in model - so it needs Python to load it. Besides `model` is not only values but also code which has to run to predict new values and Python code will not run in VB. You would rather run in VB (if it is possible) Python script which loads modle, predict value and return to VB.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to call Python code from a VB program? Also By the way, VB6 is long obsolete, VB.net is current but quite different from VB6. I wouldn't recommend VB6 for new work.